# how to repeat header row table in each print page in google chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I use #css

```
thead {display: table-header-group;}
```

but still not working in chrome version 49
(I know the version of chrome is too old but many of my computer in my office uses this version on window XP)

Help me please ? how should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be somewhere else as, `table-header-group` is well supported in chrome 49 -- https://caniuse.com/?search=table-header-group

As a side note, I think it can be legitimate question with a bit more detail or a working demo. As front end devs we should be capable of providing old browser support. In that regard you could use an old framework like bootstrap 2 or bootstrap 3 or even some other basic css reset like older version of https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ this will make your life a lot easier as they have already made things browser compatible.

Comment: How can i solve the problem please help me

Comment: @nammiieez Try a more specific css selector, e.g. `.one .two .three thead {display: table-header-group;}` May be the css rule is being overriden by some other rule.